# Polyglossia problem: "italian not defined, using english instead"

Tags: luatex, input, polyglossia

I have the problem mentioned above, reported in the log.

I have a *master-file* where I insert first a *preamble-file* with the `\input` command and then a *config-file* in the same way. The first one contains all the `\usepackage{...}` and the second one contains all the needed commands to manage the packages' work. I use LuaLaTeX of TeX Live 2015.

The polyglossia package is loaded obviously with `\usepackage{}` and the set up in the the second file is given by `\setdefaultlanguage{italian}` `\setotherlanguage{english}`.

EDIT:

1. I tried to put the set-up in the same file of the usepackage command but it gives me anyway the warning "italian not defined, using english instead"
2. The following MWE reproduces the warning.

   MWE:

   ```
   % !TeX program = lualatex
   % !TeX encoding = utf8
   % !TeX spellcheck = it_IT

   \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}

   \usepackage{fontspec}

   \usepackage{polyglossia}

   \usepackage{blindtext}


   \setmainfont{Garamond}

   \setdefaultlanguage{italian}
   \setotherlanguage{english}


   \begin{document}

   \mainmatter \part{Part one}

   \Blinddocument

   \end{document}
   ```
3. Maybe the problem is that blindtext is in english language and polyglossia recognizes it?

---

Il problema sopracitato è ovviamente riportato nel log.

Ho un file principale che raccoglie (tra gli altri) 2 files caricati con `\input`: uno contenente tutti gli `\usepackage{}` e l'altro tutte le impostazioni necesserie a regolare l'operato dei pacchetti. Uso LuaLaTeX di TeX Live 2015.

Il pacchetto polyglossia è caricato con il comando usepackage e viene impostato nel secondo file con `\setdefaultlanguage{italian}`.

EDIT:

1. Ho provato a mettere l'impostazione del linguaggio nello stesso file del caricamento del pacchetto ma riprodue lo stesso avviso
2. Ho fatto un MWE che riproduce in effetti lo stesso problema, lo si trova scritto sopra.
3. Per caso il problema è che polyglossia riconosce che il linguaggio utilizzato non è italiano?

Comment: Please include an MWE :) if it reproduces the problem, it represents the situation. I don't think you'll need to have multiple files for the MWE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to define the english language in the part of the english-blind-text and italian for the italian-sample-text and it worked.

I did not know (and I read its manual many times) that polyglossia makes a warning when recognizes a different language from the one specified.